# How to create my own table for student's t distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematica

I'm trying to compute the values of a student's t distribution, but I don't get how is it calculated. I need something like

$$
P(T<t)=t_{n,\alpha}
$$

but im not sure where does the parameter $\alpha$ enters in this coputation, $\alpha$ is the parameter for the confidence level $1-\alpha$ and $n$ is the number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: MAybe https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ is the right place to this question

Comment: Thank you, but not really, I may edit my question, I want to know how the values of $t_{n,\alpha}$ are computed.

Comment: Fully explained here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution

Comment: really? so what is the value for $t_{14,0.02}$? for 14 degrees of freedom and 0.02

Answer (score 1):

As to why you may experience some difficulties computing the values for the  Student's t-distribution, some background [comments from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#Student%27s_t-distribution) on the topic of the quantile function (inverse of the CDF), to quote:

> The evaluation of quantile functions often involves numerical methods...Quantile functions may also be characterized as solutions of non-linear ordinary and partial differential equations. The ordinary differential equations for the cases of the normal, Student, beta and gamma distributions have been given and solved.[4]

And further:

> Student's t-distribution
> (further information: [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution))

> This has historically been one of the more intractable cases, as the presence of a parameter, ν, the degrees of freedom, makes the use of rational and other approximations awkward. Simple formulas exist when the ν = 1, 2, 4 and the problem may be reduced to the solution of a polynomial when ν is even. In other cases the quantile functions may be developed as power series.[8]

My advice, get good technical support as this has been described as 'one of the more intractable cases', but with special exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I see, so its not easy to calculate the values? I was trying to make a function in mathematica to give the values, so the best way is just to look for them in tables? the thing is that I was confused, so I need the inverse function and not the CDF.